# Getting specific Azure Object Tag not just a resource group?

Tags: azure, powershell

I need to get the Specific Azure Object with a specific Tag like **Dev-Tag** and **Test-Tag**
using the command in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.resources/get-aztag?view=azps-5.1.0

This one is working with the Resource Group object only:

```
$TagName = 'Test-Tag'
Get-AzResourceGroup | Where-Object {$_.Tags.Keys -match $TagName} | OGV
```

But this one is failed with nothing returned:

```
$TagName = 'Test-Tag'
Get-AzResource | Where-Object {$_.Tags.Keys -match $TagName} | OGV
```

So how to rectify the code above so it can be used to export all objects with those two tags as above, not just Resource groups?

Comment: Hi, did you check my last comments?

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
Get-AzResource | Where-Object {$_.TagsTable -match $TagName} | OGV
```

Answer (score 1):

Another solution is

```
Get-AzResource | Where-Object {$_.Tags.Keys -eq $TagName} | OGV
```

Comment: same thing, no result returned.

Comment: How many subscriptions do you have? if you have many subscriptions then you need to select the correct subscription first
Select-AzSubscription "{SubscriptionId}"

Comment: Try
Get-AzResource | Where-Object {$_.Tags.Keys -contains $TagName}